# Is mTLS faster when both client and server is authenticated after handshake

Tags: ssl

Reading mTLS from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication)

Is mTLS in microservices and the communication between services faster than if only TLS?

I mean if using only TLS the handshaking occurs each time a communication is being established between client & server.

If mTLS the handshaking only occurs once and the connection is kept to next communication/connection - and therefore faster?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct.
Mutual authentication means that a client certificate is requested by the server **additionally** to the normal TLS handshake in order to authenticate the client. As for keeping the established TS connection open or using session resumption: this is possible for both "normal" TLS and TLS with mutual authentication.